# Ruby/EventMachine Packet Parser

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I am trying to write a custom EM::Protocol module that can pack/unpack structured binary packets.  Packet structure should be defined as name/format pairs, either as a string, some other easily parsable format, or some sort of DSL.

Some quick code to get the idea across:

```
module PacketProtocol
    def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    def receive_data(data)
        # retrieve packet header
        # find matching packet definition
        # packet.unpack(data)
    end

    module ClassMethods
        def packet(defn)
            # create an instance of Packet (see blow) and shove it
            # somewhere i can get to later.
        end
    end
end

module MyHandler
    include PacketProtocol
    packet '<id:S><len:S><msg:A%{len}>'
end

EM.run do
     EM.start_server '0.0.0.0', 8080, MyHandler
end
```

My goal is to minimize runtime complexity.  Packet definitions are static per execution, so I would like to avoid this (crude) implementation:

```
class Packet
    FmtSize = {
        'S' => 2, 
        'A' => Proc.new {|fmt| fmt[1..-1].to_i }
    }

    def initialize(defn)
        @fields = defn.scan(/<([^>]+):([^>]+)>/)
    end

    def pack(data)
        data.values.pack @fields.map { |name, fmt| fmt % data }.join
    end

    def unpack(defn)
        data = {}
        posn = 0
        @fields.each do |name, len|
            fmt = len % data
            len = FmtSizes[fmt[0]]
            len = len.call(fmt) if len.class == Proc
            data[name.to_sym] = bytes[posn..posn + len - 1].unpack(fmt)[0]
            posn += len
        end
        data
    end
end

data = { :id => 1, :len => 5, :msg = 'Hello' }
packet = Packet.new '<id:S><len:S><msg:A%{len}>'
packed = packet.pack(data)

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
    x.report('slow') {
        100000.times do
            unpacked = packet.unpack(packed)
        end
    }
    x.report('fast') {
        100000.times do
            data = {}
            data[:id] = packed[0..1].unpack('S' % data)
            data[:len] = packed[2..3].unpack('S' % data)
            data[:msg] = packed[4..8].unpack('A%{len}' % data)
        end
    }
end

# output:
#              user     system      total        real
# slow     1.970000   0.000000   1.970000 (  1.965525)
# fast     0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.146227)
```

Of the two examples, using the Packet class appears to be several magnitudes slower.

SO.  The question is:

Is there a way (or a gem) that allows you generate code at runtime (other than simply eval'ing strings)?

**EDIT:**

Just found [BinData](http://bindata.rubyforge.org/).  While it's feature-set is nice, it benchmarks much slower as well.